# Buy 2 get 1 free across all products in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store

I'd like to offer "buy 2 get 1 free" on my site which sells CDs. So if people put more than two items in their cart, the cheapest is free.

Using the "Buy X get Y" discount type, I can only seem to get this to work if they buy three of the same product, but if they buy three different ones.

Is there a way to do this in Expresso? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just got this reply from DevDemon:

*There is no built in way in the current Exp-resso Store discount system to do this with cross products. They must be the same product.
Using the Extension capabilities of ExpressionEngine you could however write an extension that does this logic and make the deals.*

If anyone ever does make an extension for this would be great – my coding skills don't stretch to that!